# Optimal method to query specific items

Tags: swift, realm

I have a list of

> Sensor

Items in my realm database.

```
class Sensor: Object {

@objc dynamic var sensorID: Int8 = 0
@objc dynamic var value: Int16 = 0
@objc dynamic var timestamp: Int64 = 0
@objc dynamic var location: Location?
@objc dynamic var isIndoor: Bool = true
@objc dynamic var synced: Bool = false
}
```

What is the most optimal method to get all items, that are newer than 24 hours.

I wrote this method

```
 func getSensors() -> [Sensor] {
    guard let items = RealmManager.shared.getObjectsWith(type: Sensor.self), let sensors = Array(items) as? [Sensor] else {
        return []
    }
    return sensors.filter({$0.value != -1 && Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval($0.timestamp)).differenceInHours() < 24})
}
```

but if I have about 100000 items, it first gets all that items and after that makes a filter, which is not optimal and takes a long time.

How can I write query to get all items, with newer than 24 hours?

Thanks.

Comment: Rather than that convenience API use a predicate to filter the items in the database.

Comment: But predicate also working on list yes? I mean in any case we will need first to get all Sensors, and after that write predicate on it.
Thanks.

Comment: In Realm all the reads are _lazy_ so the objects are not actually loaded into memory until they are read. When you cast the Results to an array ie `let sensors = Array(items) as? [Sensor]` you're reading all the objects, that's why the process is slow. Instead you keep with the Results objects (which behaves really similar to an Array) and after that you can query from that object too.

Comment: ah ok got it, thanks

Comment: In every good database you can make the query **in** the database (pseudo code `getobjects(withQuery: NSPredicate)`) which is much more efficient than reading all objects and filter in code.

Comment: Don't convert your Result<Items> to an Array, this is where you loose performance. First filter them and sort them, THEN if you want, convert to an Array (but it is better to never do this).

Comment: Thanks, and how should I get direct items from Result<Items>?